# changing value of dynamically generated input field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui, dynamic-values

i am trying to change the value of dynamically generated input field.

the scenario:

i have a button called `add items`, when clicked it append three input fields named as `itemname`,`units` and `unitprice` of which `itemname` has a jqueryui `autocomplete` and `working great`, but i am also listing `keypress event` of `itemname field` so when user press enter after selecting required itemname from autocomplete it should get units and price of the itemname which user has selected using autocomplete the code:

```
var count = 1;
    $('#add-items').click(function () {
        $('#items').append('<div><br><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>. <input type="text" name="itemname[]" id="itemname-' + count + '" class="itemname" placeholder="item name"/>\n\
                <input type="text" name="units[]" id="units-' + count + '" size="10" placeholder="units" style="text-align: right"/>\n\
                <input type="text" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice-' + count + '" size="10" placeholder="unit price" style="text-align: right"/>\n\
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove-items"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div>');
        $('#itemname-' + count).autocomplete({
            source: "<?= site_url('administrator/item-autocomplete') ?>",
            minLength: 2
        });
        $('#itemname-' + count).on('keypress', function (e) {
            var name = jQuery(this).val();
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= base_url() ?>administrator/get-unit-and-price/",
                    data: {name: name},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.valid == true) {
                            //document.getElementById('units-' + count).value = data.unit;
                            //document.getElementById('unitprice-' + count).value = data.price;
                            $('#units-' + count).attr('value', data.unit);
                            $('#unitprice-' + count).attr('value', data.price);
                            //$('#units-' + count).val(data.unit);
                            //$('#unitprice-' + count).val(data.price);
                        } else {
                            alert(data.html);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        count++;
    });
```

everything working great, but its not changing the value of unit and unitprice value, i have also tried alerting the `data.unit` and `data.price` and its alerting the proper value from database..

i am wondering what i need to do more so that it works.. looking for suggestion and help, thanks in advance.. sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting the solution so that others might get some help... :)

`::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::`

addedd `data-count` to the dynamic input field `itemname[]`

and modified the success function of ajax:

```
$('#units-' + thecount).attr('value', data.unit);
$('#unitprice-' + thecount).attr('value', data.price);
```

now things are working and when i press enter it also changes the value of `units[]` and `unitprice[]` input field,

`::::::::::::::updated solution::::::::::::::::`

```
var count = 1;
    $('#add-items').click(function () {
        $('#items').append('<div><br><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>. <input data-count="'+ count +'" type="text" name="itemname[]" id="itemname-' + count + '" class="itemname" placeholder="item name"/>\n\
                <input type="text" name="units[]" id="units-' + count + '" class="units" size="10" placeholder="units" style="text-align: right"/>\n\
                <input type="text" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice-' + count + '" class="unitprice" size="10" placeholder="unit price" style="text-align: right"/>\n\
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove-items"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></div>');
        $('#itemname-' + count).autocomplete({
            source: "<?= site_url('administrator/item-autocomplete') ?>",
            minLength: 2
        });
        $('#itemname-' + count).on('keypress', function (e) {
            var name = jQuery(this).val();
            var thecount = jQuery(this).data('count');
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= base_url() ?>administrator/get-unit-and-price/",
                    data: {name: name},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.valid == true) {
                            $('#units-' + thecount).attr('value', data.unit);
                            $('#unitprice-' + thecount).attr('value', data.price);
                        } else {
                            alert(data.html);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        count++;
    });
```

thanks to every one....